# Why I cannot cast raw collection elements in stream API?

Tags: java, java-stream

Consider having 2 snippets

```
List<?> list=...
list.stream().map(Map.class::cast).map(m->m.get("whatever")). ... //compiles and works fine

List rawList=...
rawList.stream().map(Map.class::cast).map(m->m.get("whatever")). ... //does not compile
```

Second stream casting does not work as `map` returns `Stream` while in first example it returns `Stream<Map>`. Why is that?

Comment: Does any of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it) answer your question?

Comment: Essentially, the rule is "once a raw type, forever a raw type" :)

Comment: Will remember that rule that is for sure, thanks.